# Running JMeter in batch loop

Tags: for-loop, cmd, jmeter

I'm trying to find out how to run jmeter script multiple times using "for" in cmd. Here is what I've got so far:

```
for /l %x in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) do jmeter -n -t test_for_test.jmx -e -l %x.jtl
```

But I'm getting only two files (1.jtl and 3.jtl) after script execution.
What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `for /l %x in (start step end) do ...` or `for %x in (v1 v2 v3 v4 ... )` but not both at the same time

Comment: Try this command. 

for /l %x in (1,1,10) do jmeter -n -t test_for_test.jmx -e -l %x.jtl

Syntax is 
       FOR /L %%parameter IN (start,step,end) DO command

Comment: @i474232898 Can you please accept my answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use below command to loop 10 times.

```
for /l %x in (1,1,10) do jmeter -n -t test_for_test.jmx -e -l %x.jtl
```

Here is the [complete syntax of **for** loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html).

**Syntax**

```
  FOR /L %%parameter IN (start,step,end) DO command
```

**Key**

start       : The first number

step        : The amount by which to increment the sequence 
   end         : The last number

command     : The command to carry out, including any 
                 command-line parameters.

%%parameter : A replaceable parameter:
                 in a batch file use %%G (on the command line %G)